# Custom page-break in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination

I have a ruby on rails application where in a particular view ,I have some data which is being represented in format of table . Now the user can take a print out of this page by press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> . But some of my users asking to insert page break after particular sections in that table (some contiguous rows represent a particular section) .So that the table data will be printed section wise in separate pages.

Please help me how do it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to look at [page-break-*](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/) CSS properties.

Comment: Thanks @maxd..It is working fine for me !!

Comment: This question is CSS related and has nothing to do with rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set css inside head tag ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @media print {
             
            tr ,tr.page-break{display: block;  }        
            .pagey {page-break-after: always;}
        }  
    </style>
    <title>VB</title>
</head>
<body>
    press ctrl + p = print <br><br>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="pagey">
            <td>3 br</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks rate it